Baffled with system crashing constantly
Desktop computer

ASUS TUF Gaming X570-Plus (Wi-Fi), BIOS 4802
AMD Ryzen 9 5900X
32GB DDR4 PC4-17000
RX6600
SSD Samsung 860 EVO 1TB
Windows 11 Pro 23H2 Build 22631.3296

Since ten days ago, computer started crashing about twice day, most often when its idle, but a couple times while I was working (blue screen). Time between from booting to crash varies from less than an hour to more than ten hours.
Things I've tried, without any success:

Dusted and vaccumed all fans
Replaced all RAM
Replaced video card
Updated drivers
Uninstalled latest Windows updates
Checked SMART status with CrystalDiskInfo ("all good")
Run DISM and SFC, no errors.
The Event Viewer shows nothing that I see as relevant. The last activity after each crash is a Distributed COM warning, but there are hundreds of those, and most do not align with the crashes.
Checked the crash dumps, and I see no pattern (different modules in different crashes):


I own another computer with the same specs. Checking with HWInfo64, the only difference I noted is that the crashing computer shows a higher CPU Package temp. This temp is at 66C now (with a peak of 85C), while on the healthy computer it shows 56C with a peak of 72C. I don't know if this is relevant at all.
At this state I don't know what else to try. Should I replace the motherboard? The processor? Is there anything else I should check?

The temperature doesn't seem to be a problem: 66C with a peak of 85C is not dangerous. If in all the .dmp files the crash is happening in ntoskrnl.exe which is not frequently called from some driver (set BlueScreenView menu Options to drivers only in crash stack), then the best guess is a RAM problem. Run MemTest86 for many hours, even overnight, to fully check the RAM (but also the general functioning).


Is there an error code on the blue screen? 2) Have you used Samsung Magician to make sure the drive has up-to-date firmware? 3) If the other computer has the same model of processor, you could swap them to see if the problem follows the processor.



If you've got another SATA data cable, you could try that. 5) What is the make and model of the PSU?


@harrymc: I replaced the RAM yesterday, and it didn't make a difference.

@AndrewMorton: Thanks. 1) No error code in the blue screen, and the drivers vary between crashes. 2) Firmware is up to date. 3) I could try that, not easy because both computers are not in the same location. 4) I'll try that. 5) Rosewill CAPSTONE Series, CAPSTONE-550-M, 550W

If changing the SATA cable doesn't fix it, then, if that 32 GB of RAM is spread over 4 sticks, you could try going to 16 GB with just 2 sticks (one per channel). It sounds like that'll be an easier test than swapping the CPUs for now.

I already replaced the entire ram. But I can try to swap the sticks location (I now have 32GB in two sticks).

Since you seem to have ruled out disk corruption or bad memory, its likely a driver problem seeing its SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION and REFERENCE_BY_POINTER errors. You can make use of the built in windows driver verifier (run verifier.exe) (a simple howto from tomshardware: https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/fix-system-service-exception-error-in-windows)

Verifier gave me nothing (it failed on a video driver after a day, and started a boot loop, and that driver I had installed way after the crashes started). But just by trial and error I found that the culprit is the Bluetooth Driver. The computer does not crash if I remove the Bluetooth dongle. I reinstalled the drivers several times and the crashes keep  happening if the dongle is plugged in. The question now is how I'll get to use my bluetooth devices.

@MartinArgerami You might be able to find a Bluetooth dongle which uses a different chip to the one you've got at the moment.

Yes, I've been trying to find one this morning. It is not easy to determine the chipset, though. What I did is buy a "Bluetooth 5.4", as opposed to my current 5.1, in the hopes that it uses a different driver.

What is your output in Hardware monitor in bios for your PSU? Are Voltage values in their parameters (max deviation from voltage of 3%)?

Voltages seem to be fine. I think I have solved the problem but I'll wait for a longer period of stability to confirm. Then I'll update with the details.

(I'm assuming the problem is solved; I've gone from 2+ crashes a day to 48 hours and counting of no crashes)
As mentioned in the comments, it was the bluetooth driver. Noticing that there were no crashes when I removed the bluetooth dongle, I bought a different dongle. Since the one causing the crashes was a 5.1, I bought a 5.4 with the expectation that it would require a different driver.
Before anything I uninstalled all bluetooth drivers from the device manager. This generated a curious side effect that was that the screensaver would not engage: when the time to engage the screensaver would come, the screen would black out for a second and then come back. The screensaver started working correctly when the new bluetooth driver got installed.
The new dongle made Windows install the Barrot Bluetooth 5.4 Adapter driver, as opposed to the previous Realtek Bluetooth 5.1 Adapter driver, that is possibly the culprit. A 24+hour run of Verifier.exe did not find anything wrong with the old driver, though the driver kept crashing the system regularly.
